# Sorting DOM nodes with jQuery - current code alternates reversing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have the following codepen that I created as an excerpt of the site I am working on: http://codepen.io/barrychapman/pen/BzJGbg?editors=1010

When loading the page, you can see that there are 6 boxes. The first one is enabled, while the other 5 are disabled. Clicking on the `Add to Metric 2` button will enable the second box.

Once you have done that, click on `Resort` and you will see the behavior that happens. I have the relabeling of the field headers turned off so you can see the behavior firsthand. You will see that the fields are now: [1,2,6,5,4,3].

If you click `Resort` again, it correctly sorts the fields as [1,2,3,4,5,6]. Click it again, and it is back to the way it was. This is the piece of code that is being used for this:

```
$('#target_metrics > div.disabled').each(
  function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#target_metrics').find('div.metric-template:not(.disabled)').last().after($this);
  }
);
```

I am completely stumped on this. What I want to do, essentially, is to sort the fields once a field has been added/enabled/disabled/removed/whatever - to the same order. I have several bound data elements to these nodes, so preserving the order would be greatly beneficial.

**Update**

As an example of the behavior that is undesired, follow these steps:

- Click `Resort`
- Click `Add to Metric 2`
- Click `Resort`

  Notice that Metric 2 is enabled at the end of the row.
- Click `Resort`

  Notice now that Metric 2 is in the right place.
- Click `Resort` again.

  It has now resorted the other fields.

Comment: Is expected result for order to only be  returned as `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`?

Comment: @guest271314 that is correct.

Comment: If `Metric 2` is already positioned next to `#1`, what is purpose of re-ordering elements?

Comment: Follow the update instructions, and you will see the behavior i refer to

Comment: Yes, though what is desired behaviour? What is sort algorithm?

Comment: i just want 1,2,3,4,5,6 in that sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're *saying* you want it `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` but that would mean you don't care if they are disabled or not.  Either way, you can avoid a lot of this and just run `Array.prototype.sort` on the elements.

You should always avoid multiple sequential DOM changes where possible (such as while iterating over an array-like object) - **get the data, do the work, put it back**.

Also, if you wanted to group them by disabled-ness while also sorting, you could just sort them all, then filter them out into two separate arrays and put that back on the page.

Be sure to check out **[MDN's Array.sort() article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** if you haven't already.

### JS (non-grouped)

```
// true === Descending order
var direction = false;

function reorderNodes( dir ) {
  var $target = $('#target_metrics');
  var $metricDivs = Array.prototype.sort.call($target.children('div').detach(), function ( a, b ) {
    var _a = a.querySelector('.idx');
    var _b = b.querySelector('.idx');
    if ( _a && _b ) {
      if ( _a.innerHTML > _b.innerHTML ) {
        return dir ? 1 : -1;
      }
      if ( _a.innerHTML < _b.innerHTML ) {
        return dir ? -1 : 1;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  });
  $target.append($metricDivs);
}
```

And call this on each button click (assuming you want to allow to alternate direction of sorting on click - otherwise just don't change `direction`)

```
reorderNodes(direction);
direction = !direction;
```

http://codepen.io/dhenson02/pen/WxdLwA

**For the grouped version, check this fork:**

http://codepen.io/dhenson02/pen/ZOvVpJ

Answer (score 0):

If you're sorting your DOM nodes merely to change the display order then this is unecessary work, you can use the CSS [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property to reorder them if they're a flex item.